# Switch to newly committed branch without affecting code of master branch

Tags: git, git-branch

So I have my git repo where I have made changes on the master branch **which is not committed**.

Now on the repo there's to a **new** branch.

I want to pull that **new** branch code, but I don't want it to affect my master branch's code, since the code for master branch is uncommitted.

Guide please..

Comment: What do you mean, more exactly? Normally, if you pull changes, that changes your code *by definition*.

Comment: As it stands your question is unclear. On which branch is the commit in question? Why do you fear it will alter your master branch? Are you talking about uncommited changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you should to stash your changes on master and pull and do whatever you are trying to do, and then finally unstash your changes.

```
git stash
git pull # Or whatever else you want to do
# Now back on master branch
git stash pop
```

This will store your local changes and revert your HEAD. You can then later apply those store changes!

Comment: so I will do git stash to the master.
now I pull the code. I am still at master, and now I will have to checkout to from master right.

Answer (score 1):

So here's how I did it.

```
git stash #to have the track of uncommitted code
git pull #to get the latest code and branch
git checkout new #to switch the new branch.
```

Now so If I want to switch to master branch with my old uncommitted code,

```
git checkout master
git stash pop
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Sounds good! By the way, git stash pop applies your changed and then delete the stashed copy. Git stash apply will apply your changes without deleting the stashed copy. Most of the time you just want git stash pop.

Comment: I always wanted git stash pop :)

Comment: Also, stashes can be applied in any branch. You could on theory apply your changes onto the new branch of you wanted. Stashes are just a diff, so they usually work even if they were not applied to the same code. I don't think you need this information, but it might be useful to know eventually.